# OpenGL 2.1 textures lookup table created with fragment shader

Tags: opengl

OpenGL 2.1 scenario:

I have two images. I have to modify the first (each pixel individually) and later use it as a lookup table to modify the second image.

I know enough about textures to know how to do each image individually in the fragment shader (if I already have the first image as a texture when doing the second). What I am not sure is how to combine them. If I try to do them in one go it would mean recalculating many pixels for the first one which doesn't sound good.

One thing I was considering is first doing the first image, retrieve it from the fragment shader as an image to the CPU (I am not sure how to do that yet) and then pass it to another shader program as a texture to compute the second image.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, but why not just do two texture lookups in one shader?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the fragment shader operates on each pixel individually. I need for each pixel to use a texel from each image. The problem is that the first image needs to be generated first and I don't want to do it again (even partially) for each pixel because it's generation is expensive. And I don't want to do it even for just one pixel because I may reuse it.

Comment: Then it sounds like you want to render to texture, and then used that texture as input to your second phase. First google hit: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/

Comment: Thank you. I guess my vocabulary is still too short to properly search my questions. I will go over the whole tutorial but do you have any idea if it can be used for OpenGL 2.1 as well?

Comment: Looks like for render to texture to work, you'd need FBOs. These were introduced [with OpenGL 3.0](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL#OpenGL_3.0_.282008.29). But perhaps the implementation supports [GL_ARB_framebuffer_object](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_object.txt). As a sidenote, even though OpenGL ES 2 is derived from OpenGL 2, it supports FBOs, see [OpenGL ES 2, Ch. 4.4](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf)